# Cannot make a relation to table with deferrable primary key

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I'm building my first PostgreSQL database. Now it's just two tables (table A with 1:N relation to table B). Table A has a non-deferrable primary key, while table B has a deferrable primary key. When I try to add table C with a foreign key pointing to primary key of table B (another 1:N relation), PgAdmin refuses to create the table and it returns an error message:

> ERROR: cannot use a deferrable unique constraint for referenced table
>   "table_B"

From my previous searches deferrable primary key seemed to be normal solution. Is it really possible in PgAdmin? Do I need some special trick for this to run?

I use PostgreSQL 9.1.3 and PgAdmin III 1.14.3 on 32 bit Windows XP.

Comment: It would be easier if you show the command used to create your tables.

Comment: PgAdmin should have nothing to do with it.

Comment: Usually the *foreign* key is made deferrable, not the primary key. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: to be honest, I was more just testing waters than anything else. Anyway thanks to all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it's not possible. Quote from PostgreSQL [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createtable.html) about foreign key:

> The referenced columns must be the columns of a non-deferrable unique
>   or primary key constraint in the referenced table.